# how to use EmailAddressLocalService in liferay

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, liferay-6, jsp-tags

I'm try to add an additional email address for some users with the API of liferay.
according to the docs I find this:

```
addEmailAddress(long userId, String className, long classPK, String address, int typeId, boolean primary)
```

but I'm lost a little bit, I don't know how to use this method in the right way
I have this.

```
EmailAddressLocalServiceUtil.addEmailAddress(user.getUserId(),className, classPK, emailAddress2, typeId, false)
```

I don't know how to get:
-className
-classPK
-typeId

is there some way to obtain this parameters or I need to specify this parameters manually?

Some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EmailAddressService` is used for storing emails related with different Liferay's entities (eg. User's *Contact* or *Organization*). In case of Contact (what you are propably trying to do) `ClassName` is `Contact.class.getName()` and `classPK` is user's contact object ID. `TypeID` is id of an emaill address type related with current entity (for *Contact* the types are **Email Address 1**, **2** and **3**).

I have a simple groovy script that does as follows:

1. Get *User* from *UserLocalServiceUtil*
2. Obtain proper className, classPK and typeID (default constant value from portal.properties)
3. Add new email address to previously obtained user

Code:

```
import com.liferay.portal.model.Contact
import com.liferay.portal.model.ListTypeConstants
import com.liferay.portal.model.User
import com.liferay.portal.service.EmailAddressLocalServiceUtil
import com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext
import com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil
import com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil

User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByScreenName(PortalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId(), "someuser")

String className = Contact.class.getName()
long classPK = user.getContactId()

int typeId = ListTypeConstants.CONTACT_EMAIL_ADDRESS_DEFAULT

EmailAddressLocalServiceUtil.addEmailAddress(
        user.getUserId(), className, classPK, "new@liferay.com", typeId, false, new ServiceContext())
```

Comment: Thanks you helped me alot, finally I get the right way to use this method